# Unknown column 'localhost.localdomain' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, linux

```
insert into user (Host,User,Password) values ('localhost.localdomain','elcastle',PASSWORD('elca110'));
```

When I use this code while using MySQL I got this error

```
Unknown column 'localhost.localdomain' in 'field list'
```

What should I change to fix this error?

Comment: It looks like you're inserting into the `mysql.user` table. Why aren't you using [CREATE USER](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-user.html)?

Comment: are you sure, you are executing same SQL ?

Comment: Yes im sure sir.

Comment: How can I use create user command to do the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

You have another SQL statement, in your script (or an included script) that does a (select / insert / update) by specifying a "localhost.localdomain" column that does not exist in the target table.

Comment: hmm so how can I add localhost.localdomain column?